# Set property for each object in a list IF a different property matches a value from a different list

Tags: c#, list

Ok so the title is very confusing, my apologies.

I have a list of objects, each with an identifier and a second property:

```
public class someFoo
{
  int Identifier {get; set;}
  someType someBar {get; set;}
}
```

And I have a list of identifiers. I want to select the objects with a matching identifier and set someBar on those objects. Whats the most efficient way to do this in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class SomeFoo
{
    public int Identifier {get; set;}
    public someType someBar {get; set;}
}

public void DoStuff(IEnumerable<SomeFoo> foos, IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    //Algorithimically searching for a value in a Set is faster than in a list
    ISet<int> idsAsSet = ids as ISet<int> ?? new HashSet<int>(ids);

    var itemsWeWantToChange = foos.Where(f => idsAsSet.Contains(f.Identifier ));

    foreach(var item in itemsWeWantToChange)
    {
        item.someBar = ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the syntax I was looking for. I found a similar one using Any() instead of Contains(). The tip about using a set is great.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using class instead of object?

```
public class someFoo
{
int Identifier {get; set;}
someType someBar {get; set;}
}
List<someFoo> yourList = new List<someFoo>();

// fill your list here.

someFoo specifiedFoo = yourList.Where(i=> i.Identifier == X).FirstOrDefault(); 
// x = your id  
// you also need to import Linq.

specifiedFoo.someBar = yourBar; // set it with your bar.
```

Comment: I'm not very used to c#. Fixed the question to say class. In your solution though, X is a single value, whereas I need to check against a list of Xs. Can I have a foreach inside that lambda?

Comment: If you have more than one item in your list that have the same Identifier than removing FirstOrDefault(); and adding ToList(); will give you a List of items that have identifier of your value.
But if you have a value list that you should check , create a list of that values and give X in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

The code below is checking every value in the list of "yourValues" from "yourList" and if exists; adding them in "existingList".

```
    List<someFoo> yourList = new List<someFoo>();
    List<int> yourValues = new List<int>();
    List<someFoo> existingList = new List<someFoo>();

    yourList = database.GetMyList(); // For example i filled the first list with datas coming from database.

    foreach (var x in yourValues)
    {
       someFoo existingFoo = yourList.Where(i => i.Identifier == x).FirstOrDefault();
        if(existingFoo != null)
        {
            // Do your things here
            existingFoo.someBar = myBar;
            existingList.Add(existingFoo);
        }
    }
```